# How to install python 3.9.1 natively support to Apple silicon

Tags: python, macos, installation, apple-m1, rosetta

How to install python 3.9.1 natively support to Apple silicon without rosetta? When I download python 3.9.1 from python.org and install it, it always need me to install rosetta, which reduce the speed significantly.

Per python website
Installer news
3.9.1 is the first version of Python to support macOS 11 Big Sur. With Xcode 11 and later it is now possible to build “Universal 2” binaries which work on Apple Silicon. We are providing such an installer as the macos11.0 variant. This installer can be deployed back to older versions, tested down to OS X 10.9. As we are waiting for an updated version of pip, please consider the macos11.0 installer experimental.

What does it mean? Thank you

Comment: What does *what* mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install Homebrew https://brew.sh/

and then install python via terminal

> brew install python@3.9